# Tags as variables are not supported in environment

Tags: azure-devops, yaml

I was trying to use a variable as tag while executing the deploy job using the environment template. But from https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/1015274/yaml-variable-names-not-expanded-for-tags-on-envir.html,  it's evident that ADO doesn't support variables as tags in environment deployments. For example, this works

```
   variables:
      envName: 'EnvironmentName'
      vmTag: 'vm-test-01'
   environment: 
     name: "EnvironmentName"
     resourceName: 'vm-test-01'
     resourceType: "virtualMachine"
     tags: "vm01"
   strategy:
     runOnce:
        deploy:
          steps:
             - powershell: write-host "This is $(VMName)"
```

but this doesn't

```
     name: "$(envName)"
     resourceType: "virtualMachine"
     tags: "$(vmTag)"
   strategy:
     runOnce:
        deploy:
          steps:
             - powershell: write-host "This is $(VMName)"
```

Does anyone know of an alternate or a workaround for this?

Thanks

**UPDATE: This is what I've tried**

multistage-pipeline.yml

```
- stage: "deploytouservm"
      displayName: "Stage - Deploy To User VM"
      dependsOn: "build"
      variables:
              - name: envName
                value: "environmentName"
              - name: userVM
                value: "vmName01" #this value is dynamically generated
              
      - template: templates\jobs\deploy-template.yml
              parameters:
                     envName: $(envName)
                     vmName: $(userVM)
```

deploy-template.yml

```
parameters:
    - name: envName
    - name: vmName
jobs:
    - deployment: "deployJob"
      environment: ${{ parameters['envName']}}.${{ parameters['vmName']}}
      displayName: "Deploy - SCOM To User VM"
      strategy:
          runOnce:
              deploy:
                  steps:
```

Comment: can you explain what the issue you want to have solved?

Comment: I would like to work out a way to pass a dynamic variable to the property Tags under environment. For example, I have a list of user vms under one environment and I would like to deploy an application to one of the user vms identified using tags

Comment: Since you have already mentioned that this is no possible I'm afraid that you can't do this. Your approach was actually to find someone who knows workaround, right?

Comment: That's correct.

Answer (score 1):

Try using [parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema?view=azure-devops&tabs=example%2Cparameter-schema#parameters) instead of variables:

```
parameters:
- name: envName
  default: EnvironmentName
jobs:
- deployment: VMDeploy
  displayName: Test_script
  environment:
    name: ${{ parameters.envName}}
    resourceType: VirtualMachine
```

---

```
azure-pipelines.yml

stages:
- stage:
  variables:
    EnvironmentName: Prod
  jobs:
  - template: steps.yml
    parameters:
      myParameter: Test
....

steps:yml
parameters:
- name: myParameter
jobs:
- deployment: deployment

  environment: ${{ parameters['myParameter']}}
  strategy:
  ...
```

Comment: Thank you, this works if I hard-code the value of ```envName``` and ```vmTag```. But I would need to dynamically pass the values, cause I generate the value of the tag based on the user(using user's email) who triggered the build/deployment.

Comment: You may try [Template](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/templates?view=azure-devops#insert-a-template) and [Template expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/templates?view=azure-devops#template-expression-functions).

Comment: Do you have an example I could try? I tried the template insertion using parameters, but it did not accept a variable for the value of resourceName.

Comment: Thanks for that, but I'm trying to pass a variable for the environment property Tags or the resource name. I've updated my question with what I've tried using your example, but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: It doesn't support passing a variable as a parameter to a template. But you could set a variable on template and reuse: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/templates?view=azure-devops#variable-reuse.